# How to log in to phpMyAdmin with WAMP, what is the username and password?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, phpmyadmin, passwords

What does the word "root" mean in [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin)?

Whenever I write `localhost/phpmyadmin` on the address bar, I am asked to enter a username and a password, but I don't know what they are. I don't remember when and where I set them. From where can I get my username and password to login to phpMyAdmin?

Comment: i did. I searched alot. this is where i saw name root so many time. but they all where discussing some different issues and i never saw a single line "Try username = root and password is blank." anywhere until i posted it here

Comment: The 'root' is the administrator on Unix and Unix like operating systems.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 359, accepted):

Try username = root and password is blank.

Comment: You can also add to your **/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php** file this line: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;

Comment: Hi, it will login into phpmyadmin, but not logged in adminer which is provided by wamp server. Have you any idea?? Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

Username: root

Password:

(No password set)

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes it doesn't get login with `username = root` and `password`, then you can change the default settings or the reset settings.

Open `config.inc.php` file in the phpmyadmin folder

Instead of

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

change it to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Do not specify any password and put the user name as it was before, which means `root`.

E.g.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

This worked for me after i had edited my `config.inc.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD for 'root'@'localhost' = password('yournewpassword');
```

Check this out...
https://hsnyc.co/how-to-set-the-mysql-root-password-in-localhost-using-wamp/

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was

```
username : root
password : mysql
```

Using : **Wamp server 3.1.0**

Answer (score 0):

I installed Bitnami WAMP Stack 7.1.29-0 and it asked for a password during installation.
In this case it was

```
username: root
password: <password set by you during install>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes accessing php my admin from other servers such as UwAmp can create problems. If it navigates to a login page simply use

**Username:** root

**Password:** root