# how to log in to PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, windows-7, phpmyadmin

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012052/how-to-log-in-to-phpmyadmin-with-wamp-what-is-the-username-and-password) thread.
it says I should set username to "root" and blank the password. but when I tried to do this, it says :

> Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see
>   AllowNoPassword)

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you value your data, you should not set an empty password.  You should set a complex password and not tell it to anyone.  You're lucky that your admin (or whoever packaged up the configuration for you) denied your attempt to use an empty password for access.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the password: usbw

This is the standard password.

Comment: I tired it and it says :  #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Comment: then your password is different. But i have no idea what it is than. sorry