# Local host password in Wampserver

Tags: wampserver

I am working on a project that has previously been done by some other person,
I have copied all the server files in C:\wamp\www and then i started wampserver and clicked localhost it opened the window shown in image i have uploaded ,now it requires a password and login.

[local host window image in wampserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCQEN.png)

Comment: where is image?

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow, i uploaded the image but don't know why it didn't appear

Comment: You can try again.

Comment: A J - i have uploaded the image link , kindly see

Comment: OK. I have edited your post to include the image properly.

Comment: A J- i have edited my post , kindly see the link

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link, this question was asked before.

[How to log in to phpMyAdmin with WAMP, what is the username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012052/how-to-log-in-to-phpmyadmin-with-wamp-what-is-the-username-and-password/18012178)

Btw, user= "root", password "",(just leave it blank).

On production, it is adviced to change root password or disable the root user and create other admin users.

Comment: your answer did not work ,kindly click the image link

Comment: If there is index.* in "C:\wamp\www" it might be the one asking for password. Try to read the documentation of project, it might have included credentials

Comment: the document does not contain credentials,is there any way out??

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have credentials, disable authentication from source code, and create new users, or regenerate with new credentials.